# C# two-dimensional array access throws IndexOutOfRangeException

Tags: c#, arrays, excel

I got a 2 dimensional object array and I want to read it. The program throws always an IndexOutOfRange Exception.

Here is the code:

```
Excel.Range range = activeWorksheet.UsedRange;
MessageBox.Show(range.Value2.GetType().toString()); // output: System.Object[,]
object[,] values = (object[,])range.Value2;
MessageBox.Show("l0="+values.GetLength(0)); // output: 1483
MessageBox.Show("l1"+values.GetLength(1)); // output: 221
MessageBox.Show(values.GetValue(0, 0).ToString()); // -> throws IndexOutOfRangeException
```

What the hell is going on there?! Any ideas?

Comment: Just to try. Start at index 1,1

Comment: Good ol' base-1 Excel :-)

Comment: that was it. omg. Now I remember why I never ever want to develop with microsoft tools

Comment: Because of a minor discrepancy in the decision of where to start the indexing reference? It's actually intuitive in Excel since the sheet starts at 1,1, mind you. I reckon once the decision was made eons ago, before dinosaurs roamed the Earth, they had to stick with it for continuity. Now, if you're talking about working with the Excel COM component, then you may want to take a peek at EPPlus.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excel uses 1 as start index for its dimensions. In general if you want to search for the index of the first element of unknown array:

```
int startXIndex = values.GetLowerBound(0); // 0 based dimension 
int startYIndex = values.GetLowerBound(1);
```

And do the same with the `GetUpperBound` to know the last index.

More [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.getlowerbound.aspx).